# new-webapplication command fails when a TFS Release definition runs at the same time in multiple environments, getting null exception

Tags: powershell, iis, tfs, continuous-deployment

I am trying to run a release definition for multiple environments at the same time. as part of this definition, I run a powershell script executing the new-webapplication command with certain parameters. I have 9 different environments. As part of the steps I am running a powershell script that doesn't fail when I run the release definition in sequence, I mean, running each release environment if the previous one was successful, then I don't get any errors. But If I pretend to run the same release definition for all my environments at the same time. Then it fails.

These are just a small example of my environments for this release

[image]

This is the error I am getting

```
    ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommandBut this just happens when I run the script with release agents in parallel, not in sequence as you can see on this configuration where all them have this option **Automated:After release creation**
```

[image]

And this is the script code on powershell that runs in every environment as the powershell task

```
Param
(
  [string]$remoteserver,
  [string]$directory_path,
  [string]$website_name,
  [string]$app_n
)
$ScriptBlockContent =
{
$eventlog = $args[0]
$num = $args[1]
$app_name = $args[2]

$targetdir= $eventlog+'\'+$num+'\'+$app_name
 write-host $targetdir
 write-host 'THE PATH ' $targetdir ' NOT EXIST'
 write-host 'CREATING ' $app_name' DIRECTORY'
 new-item -itemtype directory -path $targetdir -force
write-host 'CREATING ' $app_name' APPLICATION'
new-webapplication -name $app_name -force -site $num -physicalpath $targetdir 
}

Invoke-Command -Computer $remoteserver -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $directory_path, $website_name, $app_n
```

After printing each command with the -Verbose parameter, I realize that the new-webapplication command is failing with this null reference exception. 
Is the IIS not capable to manage the requests of this command at the same time from multiple threads? 
Is there anyways to rewrite myscript?

```
while(iis-is-failing)
   //re-run new-webapplication ...
```

Comment: What's the failure?

Comment: @DanielMann I updated the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

First please double check your **Queuing policies**. Queuing policies are defined in the **Options** section of the **Deployment conditions** tab.

[image]

Maek sure you didn't select *after successful deployment on another environment* in the trigger and select *allow multiple releases to be deployed at the same time*.  For the detail info of each settings please refer [Deployment conditions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/environments#conditions)

---

When you create a new environment, the default is checking the trigger.

[image]

Also pay attention to the license just like *Daniel Mann* mentioned in this question [Release Management TFS 2015 - No Parallel Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072482/release-management-tfs-2015-no-parallel-tasks)

Comment: in my case the only one that works is selecting on the deployment conditions the option after successful deployment on another environment, using your advice of deploy all of them one after another doesn't work for me